# Error 'CDC::CDC(const CDC &)': attempting to reference a deleted function MFCBreakout

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, gdi, deleted-functions

Making my Breakout Game in MFC. I store the bitmap info into a `CDC` object (Device Context Object), but since there will be different bitmaps for each block, I store the same overwritten `CDC m_blockDC` into a `std::vector<CDC> m_blockStates` and since I have five block types I store the before mentioned vector into a `std::vector<std::vector<CDC>>` so I can access each block state bitmap info using a enum `BLOCKPROPS` and their hit property which is vinculated with the index; thus, I will be accessing each block state with `m_blockStates[BLOCKTYPE][CBlock.GetHits()]`

When I try to run the program the error `'CDC::CDC(const CDC &)': attempting to reference a deleted function` appears.

This is how I store the `m_blockDC` into the bidimensional vector:

```
void CCreateWindow::LoadBlock(std::vector<LPCWSTR> FileMap, BLOCKPROP BlockProperty) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < FileMap.size(); i++)
    {
        HANDLE blockBitmap = LoadImage(0, FileMap[i], IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE); //(Instance, FileSrc, Type, PartX, PartY, Process)
        m_blockCBMP.Attach(reinterpret_cast<HBITMAP>(blockBitmap));
        pDC = this->GetDC();
        m_blockDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);

        switch (BlockProperty)
        {
        case TUFF:
            m_blockStateArray[TUFF].push_back(m_blockDC);
            break;
        case STRD:
            m_blockStateArray[STRD].push_back(m_blockDC);
            break;
        case WEAK:
            m_blockStateArray[WEAK].push_back(m_blockDC);
            break;
        case SPCL:
            m_blockStateArray[SPCL].push_back(m_blockDC);
            break;
        case INDS:
            m_blockStateArray[INDS].push_back(m_blockDC);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    //Get BitmapSize
    m_blockDC.SelectObject(&m_blockCBMP);
    m_blockCBMP.GetBitmap(&m_blockBMP);
}
```

This code is used in the `OnInitDialog()` of `CCreateWindow.cpp` and the function `PaintBlock()` within `OnTimer()` will be used to paint the blocks, or at least that's how it is suppossed to be.

Comment: Looks like `CDC` is not copyable.  Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: `std::vector` requires elements that can be copied and/or moved, but `CDC`'s copy constructor is `delete`d, so `CDC` objects can't be copied. That is what the compiler is complaining about. Try using `std::unique_ptr<CDC>` elements in your vector instead, as `std::unique_ptr` is compatible with `std::vector`.

Comment: The `CDC` is not copyable. What exactly your code does with it doesn't matter. A class may not be copyable for any number of reasons. `CDC`, according to Microsoft's documentation, represent a device context. The most likely reason is that the notion of "copying a device context" is meaningless, and it basically cannot be copied for the same reason that `std::istream` cannot be copied, basically.

Comment: You probably need to redesign your program. `GetDC` is a temporary handle, it has to be cleaned up with `ReleaseDC`. Paint in response to `ON_WM_PAINT`, and use `CPaintDC dc(this)` which has automatic cleanup.